# How to assign column values based on file path and name

Tags: r, dataframe, directory

If the `File.Name` column of `clin.info` matches an idat file in the `idat` folder, I want to assign it to a new column `Basename` and populate it as `path/idat/clin.info$File.Name`.

```
for(file in paste0(getwd(), "/idat/*.idat")){
  if(file == clin.info$File.Name) {
    clin.info$Basename <- paste0(getwd(), "/idat/", clin.info$File.Name)
  }
}
```

Traceback:

```
Error in if (file == clin.info$File.Name) { : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

For example, the current working directory has:

```
abc.idat
def.idat
ghi.txt
```

Desired Output:
`clin.info$Basename`

```
path/idat/abc.idat
path/idat/def.idat
```

Data:

```
> dput(clin.info[1:3,])
structure(list(Sample.ID = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", "TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A"), pstage = c("stage ii", "stage ii", "stage i"
), age = c("53", "53", "71"), malignancy_type = c("", "", ""), 
    days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis = c("0", "0", "0"), 
    days_to_last_follow_up = c("207.0", "207.0", "2298.0"), race = c("white", 
    "white", "white"), gender = c("male", "male", "male"), ethnicity = c("not hispanic or latino", 
    "not hispanic or latino", "not hispanic or latino"), vital_status = c("0", 
    "0", "0"), survival = c("lts", "lts", "lts"), subtype = c("2a", 
    "2a", "1a"), clust = c("2a", "2a", "1a"), File.ID.x = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), File.Name.x = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), File.ID.y = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), File.Name.y = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), File.ID = c("3a2da879-8f67-4367-b8a5-afa33c27a965", 
    "e72be882-b077-4d98-8cc8-af72524f3889", "e68f0688-b783-4f1a-9e17-67389a92a39a"
    ), File.Name = c("69886174-727c-4e79-b5ab-394778ccf609_noid_Red.idat", 
    "69886174-727c-4e79-b5ab-394778ccf609_noid_Grn.idat", "a639da8d-d87c-4b69-b49e-3bf27e20ed65_noid_Grn.idat"
    )), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Right now you are not interacting with files in any way. Do you want to add path to `clin.info$File.Name` values and store those in `clin.info$Basename` ? Or do you want check if files exist first? Error is caused because `file == clin.info$File.Name` generates logical vector of the length of `clin.info` rows, as error states, you can't have that in `if()` , you could fix that with `if(file %in% clin.info$File.Name)`  but I'm afraid it still does not do what you expect it to.

Comment: I want to check whether the files exist first, and then add path to `clin.info$File.Name`

Answer (score 0):

In this case loops only complicate things, it's all about vectors and subsetting:

```r
# idat path:
dest_dir <- file.path(tempdir(), "idat")

# first store all full paths in clin.info$Basename
clin.info$Basename <- file.path(dest_dir, clin.info$File.Name)
# then set non-existing ones to NA
is.na(clin.info$Basename) <- !file.exists(clin.info$Basename)

tibble::as_tibble(clin.info)[,c(19:20)]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   File.Name                                          Basename                   
#>   <chr>                                              <chr>                      
#> 1 69886174-727c-4e79-b5ab-394778ccf609_noid_Red.idat "C:\\Users\\marguslt\\AppD…
#> 2 69886174-727c-4e79-b5ab-394778ccf609_noid_Grn.idat  <NA>                      
#> 3 a639da8d-d87c-4b69-b49e-3bf27e20ed65_noid_Grn.idat "C:\\Users\\marguslt\\AppD…
```

Prepare reprex, load sample data & create 2 dummy files:

```
clin.info <- structure(list(Sample.ID = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", "TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A"), pstage = c("stage ii", "stage ii", "stage i"
), age = c("53", "53", "71"), malignancy_type = c("", "", ""), 
    days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis = c("0", "0", "0"), 
    days_to_last_follow_up = c("207.0", "207.0", "2298.0"), race = c("white", 
    "white", "white"), gender = c("male", "male", "male"), ethnicity = c("not hispanic or latino", 
    "not hispanic or latino", "not hispanic or latino"), vital_status = c("0", 
    "0", "0"), survival = c("lts", "lts", "lts"), subtype = c("2a", 
    "2a", "1a"), clust = c("2a", "2a", "1a"), File.ID.x = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), File.Name.x = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), File.ID.y = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), File.Name.y = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), File.ID = c("3a2da879-8f67-4367-b8a5-afa33c27a965", 
    "e72be882-b077-4d98-8cc8-af72524f3889", "e68f0688-b783-4f1a-9e17-67389a92a39a"
    ), File.Name = c("69886174-727c-4e79-b5ab-394778ccf609_noid_Red.idat", 
    "69886174-727c-4e79-b5ab-394778ccf609_noid_Grn.idat", "a639da8d-d87c-4b69-b49e-3bf27e20ed65_noid_Grn.idat"
    )), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

dest_dir <- file.path(tempdir(), "idat")
dir.create(dest_dir)
# create 2 test files out of 3
file.create(file.path(dest_dir, clin.info$File.Name[c(1,3)]))
#> [1] TRUE TRUE
fs::dir_tree(dest_dir)
#> C:\Users\marguslt\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpa27shZ/idat
#> ├── 69886174-727c-4e79-b5ab-394778ccf609_noid_Red.idat
#> └── a639da8d-d87c-4b69-b49e-3bf27e20ed65_noid_Grn.idat
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>